# Is it possible camera app without using preview layout?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an app which takes picture in background.
but it uses a preview layout which is attached to an activity.

actually i need it as plugin which do not show preview. and camera app i have developed using class which extends an activity.

i wonder how can it be possible to make it without using an activity or preview layout.

please help on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the preview layout.

```
layoutname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: please read the question carefully, i said what i need is a non-activity class implements the camera code

Comment: anyways, i got the solution.